# Wrapping text around table textbox element

Tags: html

I want to wrap text around textbox, with text at the top of the textbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PThM9.jpg)

```
<!-- ==================== Travel Details Field -->
<tr class="Field CommentRow">
<td class="LabelForm">Travel Details</td>

<td class="Value">
   <%= Html.TextArea("TravelDetails", H(genericModel.Comment), 12, 60, new { @class = "BodyWatermark", style = "width:360px" })%>
       <span class="More")>We are traveling to Naples on the 15th or May, followed by London starting on May 23rd</span>
</td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```html
<!-- ==================== Travel Details Field -->
<tr class="Field CommentRow">
<td class="LabelForm">Travel Details</td>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="boxy" style="width: 300px;height: 200px;"><br>
   
</form>

<td class="Value">
   <Html.TextArea("TravelDetails", H(genericModel.Comment), 12, 60, new { @class = "BodyWatermark", style = "width:360px" })%>
       <span class="More")>We are traveling to Naples on the 15th or May, followed by London starting on May 23rd</span>
</td>

</tr>
```